# Build on arXiv fails with error that seems completely unrelated to the document

Tags: errors, compiling, arxiv

I am trying to upload an article to arXiv. Now I'm encountering an error I have not seen before.

A line as simple as

```
\section{Lemmata and Proofs}
```

causes this error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \section
{Lemmata and Proofs}%
?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \section
{Lemmata and Proofs}%
No pages of output.
```

It's indeed the first line of its own file, included with `\input`.
The only noteworthy thing is that this is (the first section) in the appendix.

I have not consciously included any package that would tamper with appendices or section headlines, so I am at a loss as to where this error may come from.
My document class is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,american]{scrartcl}
```

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: the input file is compiled instead of the main file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't think should be since the main file contains the "compile as PDF" directive arXiv asks for, but that's a good idea that would explain the error. I'll check that, thanks.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer My bad. I looked at the last error on the page, figuring that should be the critical one, but that indeed came from the system trying to translate the input file. Building the main file failed for another reason. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to post an answer? I'd edit the question to be more general along the lines of "arXiv build fails, weird error that does not seem to make any sense". That is, if you think a question-answer pair that points people towards searching for the *real* error in arXiv's output is useful at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ulrike Fischer's hint was spot-on: that error message belonged to the output of an attempt to `pdflatex` a LaTeX file that was not the main file, i.e. did not contain `\documentclass` et al. The relevant error was further up.